# How to make a button like this? [Kotlin]

Tags: android, kotlin

[Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpMqC.jpg)

I want to make a button like this how can I do it? I want to change the color of shadow of the button.

Comment: The question is a bit too wide. What exact part of the problem do you have trouble with?

Comment: I mean the part of shadow below the button. The color is orange. It is like some kind of 3d button. On the hand, in android the button created is 2d as default

Comment: Then I think you should add details about how you created your own button currently, like snippets of code and/or XML that show what you have done so far, and the exact piece you're missing. Show your current state and what is different from the one in the picture. This will make it much easier for people who know the topic to provide a properly tailored and to-the-point answer to unblock you. In its current state, the question forces other people to write a whole thing from scratch to really help you, and not everyone is willing to spent such time.

Answer (score 2):

> need layer-list and AppcompatButton -> like this

```
  <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="293dp"
        android:layout_height="68dp"
        android:background="@drawable/yellow_btn"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Get Started"
        android:textColor="#353935"
      />
```

> and for drawable background make xml drawable layer-list

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#DFCD03"/>
            <corners android:radius="60dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="8dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#FFF273"/>
            <corners android:radius="60dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

final shape
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Create drawable name as `button_bg.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape>
                    <solid android:color="#FFC107"/>
                    <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
                </shape>
            </item>

            <item
                android:bottom="10px"
                >
                <shape>
                    <padding android:bottom="5dp"/>
                    <gradient
                        android:startColor="#FFEB3B"
                        android:endColor="#FFEB3B"
                        />
                    <corners
                        android:radius="20dp"/>
                    <padding
                        android:left="10dp"
                        android:top="10dp"
                        android:right="5dp"
                        android:bottom="10dp"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape>
                    <solid android:color="#FFEB3B"/>
                    <corners android:radius="20dp"/>

                </shape>
            </item>

            <item android:bottom="5px">
                <shape>
                    <padding android:bottom="5dp"/>
                    <gradient
                        android:startColor="#FFC107"
                        android:endColor="#FFC107"
                       />
                    <corners
                        android:radius="20dp"/>
                    <padding
                        android:left="10dp"
                        android:top="10dp"
                        android:right="5dp"
                        android:bottom="10dp"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

in your xml layout set background for button/textview

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg" // custom design 
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Get Started" />

</RelativeLayout>
```